# rewrite rules not working in apache2.conf

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i put rewrite rules in apache2.conf but not working, it should work in .htaccess (the another virtualhost using .htaccess on same server).

the rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php/adminabc
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111
RewriteRule ^.*$ /deny.html [R=302,L]
```

the full virtualhost file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/folder

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5

<Directory "/var/www/folder">
#Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
#allow from all
#AllowOverride All
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5

#####################start of .htaccess#######################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php indx.html

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#  php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.hk$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.swf|\.htm|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.woff|robots\.txt|downloader)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php  [L]


</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php/adminabc
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /deny.html [R=302,L]

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

#AuthType Basic
#AuthName "restricted area"
#AuthUserFile /var/www/folder/.htpasswd
#require valid-user
#####################end of .htaccess#######################

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

anyone can figure out the problems?

Comment: Make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded and move those rules above the other rewrite rules in that file

Comment: should i need to restart the apache2? i only use "apply changes" in webmin

Comment: You need to restart apache, or at least reload the workers, not sre what your webmin is

Comment: reloaded but not work...........